# Trying to learn SQL Aggregations and Sub-Queries

Tags: sql, count, sum, aggregate

I am trying to improve my query writing and need help with the following...

I have one table with multiple columns, including Operation_Code, Operation_Category, Downtime_In_Minutes, Downtime (as a percentage of the last 24 hours).  Each line of my results set needs to SUM(Downtime_minutes) for each Operation_Code and SUM(Count of each occurrance of the Operation_Code).  Stop will always be yesterday.  Date functions and formatting return yesterdays date.  This is not presented in the query below due to length of the code, but it works.  So, each line in the results should look like:

- StopDate
- Operation_Code
- Operation_Category
- Count (# of occurrences of each Op_Code)
- SUM (in minutes) of all downtime for each Operation_Code
- % of Last 24 hours

**Example Results:**

```
StopDate     Op_Code     OP_Category    Count       Downtime (Minutes)     % of Last 24
7/18/2021    X123        Grinder        10          720                    50%
7/18/2021    A800        Cutter         12          360                    25%      
7/18/2021    O225        Polisher        5          60                      4%
```

My query without attempting any aggregations is basically:

```
Select StopDate, 
       OpCode, 
       OpCat
From   DTS
Where  StopDate = yesterday
```

Basic question is hw do I SUM the count of occurrences and SUM the total time in minutes for each unique Operation_Code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for aggregation?  Then you can use a window function to get the ratio, which I am guessing is based on the downtime:

```
Select StopDate, OpCode, OpCat, count(*) as cnt,
       sum(Downtime_In_Minutes),
       sum(Downtime_In_Minutes) * 1.0 / nullif(sum(Downtime_In_Minutes) over ()) as 
From  DTS
Where StopDate = yesterday;
```

I assume you know how to deal with "yesterday", because you say that you already have a query.

group by StopDate;